# Why do I get an error of Invalid Parent Orgunit Id when I'm inserting in Google G Suit?

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-visualization

I got an error of Invalid Parent Orgunit Id at the time of insert organization in Google G Suit admin.

I passed true parent orgUnitid but still every time I got this error response.

> "code": 400,   "message": "Invalid Parent Orgunit Id"

- here is my code.

  **in $client->setSubject() i passed email address**

  **C01sgPOLM1 this is my customer id**  P.S. : here i passed dummy customer ID for refrence perpuse.

  ```
  public function addOrgUnits()
  {

      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
      $client->addScope([
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit',
      ]);

      $client->setSubject('ABCD);
      $payload = [
          'name' => "demo1"
      ];
      $httpClient = $client->authorize();


      $response = $httpClient->post('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/C01sgPOLM1/orgunits',
          $payload);
      if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
          $users = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

          return $this->successResponse(trans('message.organizationFound'), ['data' => $users]);
      }

      return $this->errorResponse();
  }
  ```

Comment: Where is your code? This really is not helpful.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edited question

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same behavior as you do in the [API tester](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/insert), which is weird because according to the documentation, the only required property is **name**. So, based on the documentation, you are doing everything right. My only guess right now is that there has been a change in the way the API behave, or this might be a bug. I recommend you to get in touch with the [G Suite API support team](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and report this behavior.

In the meantime, to make it work, you'll need to pass either the **parentOrgUnitId** or the **parentOrgUnitPath**. I have tested with the **parentOrgUnitPath** and it worked.

```
$payload = [
    'name' => "demo1",
    'parentOrgUnitPath' => "/"
];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: here I passed only 2 parameters which you suggested but still, I get an error of 400 and  Invalid Parent Orgunit Id message.

Comment: @anaya Can you please try using "my_customer" as the value for  customerId? Also, what is the parentOrgUnitPath you are using?